# Merging two spreadsheets using record numbers in Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel

I have two spreadsheets, one that would be considered the header and another with the details for the headers.  What I need to do is merge the two spreadsheets so that the rows show the header then the appropriate detail rows beneath.
For example:
Here is the Header Table:

1. 360  JOB 1
2. 708  JOB 2
3. 724  JOB 3

And here is the Detail Table:

1. 360  STEP 1
2. 360  STEP 2
3. 360  STEP 3
4. 708  STEP 1
5. 708  STEP 2
6. 724  STEP 1
7. 724  STEP 2
8. 724  STEP 3

I want to merge them using the ID column to get this:

1. 360  JOB 1
2. 360  STEP 1
3. 360  STEP 2
4. 360  STEP 3
5. 708  JOB 2
6. 708  STEP 1
7. 708  STEP 2
8. 724  JOB 3
9. 724  STEP 1
10. 724  STEP 2
11. 724  STEP 3

I am working with thousands of records here, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short:**

Copy and paste the two tables, and do a sorting will do.  If you want to make header row goes first, add a helper column to assist the sorting.

**Details:**

In your header table, add a column (for sorting purpose only)

```
360   JOB 1   A
708   JOB 2   A
724   JOB 3   A
```

Similar for the detail table.  Here I want to preserve the step number, so make the sorting order like B001, B002, B003... etc.

```
360   STEP 1   B001
360   STEP 2   B002
360   STEP 3   B003
708   STEP 1   B004
708   STEP 2   B005
724   STEP 1   B006
724   STEP 2   B007
724   STEP 3   B008
```

Merge the two lists by copy and paste:

```
360   JOB 1    A
708   JOB 2    A
724   JOB 3    A
360   STEP 1   B001
360   STEP 2   B002
360   STEP 3   B003
708   STEP 1   B004
708   STEP 2   B005
724   STEP 1   B006
724   STEP 2   B007
724   STEP 3   B008
```

Then do a custom sort (Level 1: Column A; Level 2: Column C).  Delete column C after sorting and you will get the needed results.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the very late answer - I just found the solution I built for this previously, and realised I had never shared it...

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. From Excel 2016, Power Query is built in to the Data ribbon under "Get and Transform" section.

Power Query can start from an existing Excel Tables and Append them together. A Query result can be delivered as an Excel Table. You can build this without writing any macro or function code - you just click around in the Power Query window.

I built a working solution which you can download from my OneDrive and try out:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: **Power Query demo - merging two sheets using record numbers**